# Ubuntu keeps getting bumped under Windows Boot Manager in UEFI BIOS after I move it above WBM, why is it happening? It won’t let me prioritize Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

When trying to put Ubuntu above Windows Boot Manager, when I move it up and exit the prompt to move around what is to boot first, it has put Windows above Ubuntu again.

Doesn’t matter if Secure Boot or Legacy support is enabled/disabled, it keeps doing this.

Device: HP Pavilion 15 cs3xxx with bios revision F.14

Comment: Curious.  My dual-boot machine uses Grub and I customize it with Grub Customizer.  Have you tried this?  It works well for me.

Comment: Nope, but I can look into it

Comment: My BIOS is set as follows:
Secure Boot: Disabled,
Boot Mode: UEFI,
1st Boot Device: UEFI: ubuntu.

I set the boot order for Ubuntu and Windows in GRUB.

Comment: Is this an HP system? Many with HP say they update UEFI (which may not be required) and then set boot order in HP's UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu). For whatever reason it does not keep setting changes beyond one reboot.

Comment: it is an HP system from late 2019